# How do I refer to the scope of a parent inside a child controller when using the "as controller" syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my `ParentController` I currently have:

```
   $scope.grid = {
                $index: null,
                view: [],
                data: []
            };
```

In my `ChildController` I currently have:

```
   .controller('ChildController', ['$Scope',
        function ($Scope) {

            $Scope.grid.$index = null;
            $Scope.grid.view = [];
            $Scope.grid.data = [];
```

From what I understand this allows me to populate $Scope.grid.data in the `ChildController`
and also have functions that can operate on the $Scope.grid.data inside the `Parent Controller`.

Now I would like to start using the "as controller" syntax. So if I understand this correctly I need to code inside the two HTML pages the controllers in my HTML like this:

```
<div data-ng-controller="ParentController as parent" ..

<div data-ng-controller="ChildController as child" ..
```

And my parent controller like this:

```
   this.grid = {
                $index: null,
                view: [],
                data: []
            };
```

If I do this then in my `ChildController` how should I refer to the grid.view? Do I somehow pass '`parent`' into the `ChildController` and then in my child use:

```
parent.grid.view = [];
```

Finally I heard that the "as controller" syntax was experimental. Has it now got past that stage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't change your code the "as" syntax doesn't make any difference.

If you changed `ParentController` to

```
this.grid = {
  $index: null,
  view: [],
  data: []
};
```

then you would still need a `$scope` reference in your `ChildController`, but you add another property:

```
   .controller('ChildController', ['$Scope',
    function ($Scope) {

        $Scope.parent.grid.$index = null;
        $Scope.parent.grid.view = [];
        $Scope.parent.grid.data = [];
```

As you can see it's not only more complicated, but you also couple the code to the HTML: If you decide to change your HTML to `ParentController as someController` your `ChildController` breaks.

So even with the "as" syntax you want `grid` to be  a property of `$scope`.